# Better way to keep track of dynamic inputs

Tags: reactjs

**Scenario**
You can add a new user to the list (First Name, and Last Name) by pressing the button "Add Human".
One row of information is one user.

In order to keep track of these dynamically added new inputs, I must store them in state and know which one to update.

**Solution**
Every time user clicks the button, I need to:

- generate an id
- add the new user boilerplate to state // {id: {firstName: null, lastName: null}}
- pass this id to the input onChange handler function
- create handler function for each field that I need to update

**Question**
Surely there has to be a better way to do this more elegantly?
This just seems like a lot of excess code. (Especially for my real life project where I have 10+ inputs per row)

**Code** [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cnlzci?file=src/App.js)

Any suggestion on how to improve this is appreciated.

Comment: You don't really need a separate handler function for every input. You have the `event.target`. Give each input a corresponding `name` attribute and use that in a single handler to determine the property to update.

Comment: oh my, how did I not think of this. Thanks! Besides the obvious improvement, is generating an ID for each new input the way to go for these types of problems?

Comment: If you've an "unknown" number of inputs then I would typically suggest using an internal GUID that persists for the life of the input.